# Some views in layout are outside the screen

Tags: android, layout

Top text "Your profile" is not visible in my layout.
In album orientation pictures are truncated.
I have added "Scroll" element, but it does not work there.

[image]

[image]

My XML is below:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@color/backNormal"
          android:orientation="vertical"
    >


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/backNormal"
            android:orientation="vertical"

        >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@color/backNormal"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            >


        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:background="@color/backNormal"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                      android:weightSum="6"
                >
            <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                          android:layout_width="0dp"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:background="@color/backNormal"
                          android:orientation="vertical"
                          android:layout_weight="4"
                          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"

                    >


                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextTitle"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text='Your profile'
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        style="@style/text_style_title"

                        />
                <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:orientation="horizontal"
                        >

                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileImageFace"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/driver"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        />
                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileImageCar"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/car"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextName"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text='Your name'
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        style="@style/text_style_normal"
                        />

                <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileEditName"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:minLines="1"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:maxLength="25"
                        style="@style/edit_style"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit"
                        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                        android:cursorVisible="true"
                        />
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextCar"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text='Car model and number'
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        style="@style/text_style_normal"
                        />

                <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileEditCar"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:minLines="1"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:maxLength="25"
                        style="@style/edit_style"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit"
                        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                        android:cursorVisible="true"
                        />

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextGenderTitle"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text='Gender'
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        style="@style/text_style_normal"
                        />


                <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:orientation="horizontal"
                              android:layout_gravity="center"
                              android:weightSum="4"
                        >

                    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/driverProfileButtonMale"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text='M'
                            style="@style/button_style_normal"
                            />

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextGender"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text='Unknown'
                            android:background="@color/backDark1"
                            style="@style/text_style_normal"
                            />

                    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/driverProfileButtonFemale"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text='F'
                            style="@style/button_style_normal"
                            />

                </LinearLayout>
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextYearTitle"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text='Year Of Birth'
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        style="@style/text_style_normal"
                        />


                <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:orientation="horizontal"
                              android:layout_gravity="center"
                              android:weightSum="4"
                        >
                    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/driverProfileButtonYearMinus"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text='-'
                            style="@style/button_style_normal"
                            />

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextYear"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text='Unknown'
                            android:background="@color/backDark1"
                            style="@style/text_style_normal"
                            />

                    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/driverProfileButtonYearPlus"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text='+'
                            style="@style/button_style_normal"
                            />


                </LinearLayout>


                <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileProgress"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                        />

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileButtonReg"
                        android:text='Registration'
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        style="@style/button_style_normal"
                        />
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextResult"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=''
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        style="@style/text_style_normal"
                        />

            </LinearLayout>
            <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: inside scroll view one single layout should be there !

Comment: Use the scroll view as parent.. You have added scroll view in the linear layout.. Remove the top linear layout.. I think it will  work..

Comment: Remove the `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"` property from the first LinearLayout of the ScrollView.

Comment: @Prakhar it will not matter :)

Comment: try adding android:fillViewPort=true; and android:measureAllChildren:true in you scroll view xml attributes.

Comment: Not understood this: "inside scroll view one single layout should be there "

Comment: @Niaz scroll view should have single child .. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android:fillViewport="true"` in your ScrollView and it will fill up the screen.

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
```

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake testing. It works!   But I see black space on the bottom. I don't know how to eliminate it. BTW  android:measureAllChildren="true" does not matter

Comment: To eliminate bottom black space I've added LinearLayout with height="500dp". So it seems all is okay. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/backNormal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true" >
```

> Rest of the code

Use `ScrollView` as a parent.
I think this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout                   
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/backNormal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            >


            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:weightSum="6"
                >

                <View
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   />

                <LinearLayout 
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:orientation="vertical"
                   android:layout_weight="4"

                  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                  >


                 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextTitle"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text='Your profile'
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    style="@style/text_style_title"

                    />
            <LinearLayout 
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:orientation="horizontal"
                    >

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileImageFace"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/driver"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    />
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileImageCar"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/car"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextName"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text='Your name'
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    style="@style/text_style_normal"
                    />

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileEditName"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:minLines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:maxLength="25"
                    style="@style/edit_style"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    />
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextCar"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text='Car model and number'
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    style="@style/text_style_normal"
                    />

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileEditCar"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:minLines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:maxLength="25"
                    style="@style/edit_style"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextGenderTitle"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text='Gender'
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    style="@style/text_style_normal"
                    />


            <LinearLayout 
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:orientation="horizontal"
                          android:layout_gravity="center"
                          android:weightSum="4"
                    >

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileButtonMale"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text='M'
                        style="@style/button_style_normal"
                        />

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextGender"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text='Unknown'
                        android:background="@color/backDark1"
                        style="@style/text_style_normal"
                        />

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileButtonFemale"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:text='F'
                        style="@style/button_style_normal"
                        />

            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextYearTitle"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text='Year Of Birth'
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    style="@style/text_style_normal"
                    />


            <LinearLayout   
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:orientation="horizontal"
                          android:layout_gravity="center"
                          android:weightSum="4"
                    >
                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileButtonYearMinus"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text='-'
                        style="@style/button_style_normal"
                        />

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextYear"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text='Unknown'
                        android:background="@color/backDark1"
                        style="@style/text_style_normal"
                        />

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileButtonYearPlus"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:text='+'
                        style="@style/button_style_normal"
                        />


            </LinearLayout>


            <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileProgress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    />

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileButtonReg"
                    android:text='Registration'
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    style="@style/button_style_normal"
                    />
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextResult"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text=''
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/text_style_normal"
                    />

        </LinearLayout>
        <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                />

       </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

but you need improve your layout with more `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`, and also deep layout level will reduce performance

Comment: Ok cool, do you use exact layout as answer, or you changed something?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/backNormal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/backNormal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/backNormal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="6" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:background="@color/backNormal"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextTitle"
                    style="@style/text_style_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Your profile" />

                <LinearLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileImageFace"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/driver" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileImageCar"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/car" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextName"
                    style="@style/text_style_normal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Your name" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileEditName"
                    style="@style/edit_style"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLength="25"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:minLines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextCar"
                    style="@style/text_style_normal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Car model and number" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileEditCar"
                    style="@style/edit_style"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLength="25"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:minLines="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextGenderTitle"
                    style="@style/text_style_normal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Gender" />

                <LinearLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="4" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileButtonMale"
                        style="@style/button_style_normal"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="M" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextGender"
                        style="@style/text_style_normal"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:background="@color/backDark1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Unknown" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileButtonFemale"
                        style="@style/button_style_normal"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="F" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextYearTitle"
                    style="@style/text_style_normal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Year Of Birth" />

                <LinearLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="4" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileButtonYearMinus"
                        style="@style/button_style_normal"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="-" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextYear"
                        style="@style/text_style_normal"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:background="@color/backDark1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Unknown" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/driverProfileButtonYearPlus"
                        style="@style/button_style_normal"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="+" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileProgress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileButtonReg"
                    style="@style/button_style_normal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="Registration" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/driverProfileTextResult"
                    style="@style/text_style_normal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but using `ScrollView` as parent and  `android:fillViewport="true"` should solve your issue. If it is not specify whether you are able Scroll after adding `ScrollView` as parent.